# Difference between "We saw hardly anything" and "We hardly saw anything"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> "We saw hardly anything"

and

> "We hardly saw anything"

Can someone explain to me the difference between these two sentences?

Comment: They are functionally equivalent, but one constrains the view while the other, the viewing.

Answer (score 1):

"We saw hardly anything" sounds like you could see just fine, but there was hardly anything *to* see.

"We hardly saw anything" suggests that there may have been something to see, but either you didn't see it, or were prevented from doing so.

Comment: Although many would use 2 meaning 1. It's less formal.